# HTML input type date fromat

Tags: html, date, format

Without finding any necessary information, does there is the possibility to make custom HTML input type='date' format? For example:

```
<label for="date_from">From</label>
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="date_from" value="{{Request::get('date_from') ?? ''}}" name="date_from">
```

[image]

I want to change, that the start of the week starts from Monday, not Sunday. And the format be 2020-04-08, not 04/08/2020. Does there are any possibility to format it to my needs?

**UPDATED**

To solve this problem I used the Jquery plugin datepicker. And ended like this:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Any luck on this?

Comment: @bigchungus I added information how I solve this problem.

Comment: I am assuming that you gave the input ```class="datepicker"```